# Rearrange array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have below data as a list in Python.

```
result = [
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "A",
   "parent": 0
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "B",
   "parent": 1
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "C",
   "parent": 1
 },
 {
   "id": 4,
   "name": "D",
   "parent": 2
 }
]
```

I would like to return in children data in a new key

```
result = [
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "A",
   "parent": 0,
   "child": [    
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "parent": 1,
        "child": [ 
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "D",
                "parent": 2
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "C",
        "parent": 1
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? I have tried some solutions from other questions of stackover. However, ntg worked.

Respone I am getting with solution code is below. Original code is still available in the tree

````
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A",
            "parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "B",
                    "parent": 1,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "D",
                            "parent": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "C",
                    "parent": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "D",
                    "parent": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "C",
            "parent": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "D",
            "parent": 2
        }
    ]
    ```
````

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The effectiveness of this will depend on the size of your dataset - but it should give you a starting point.

Create an index. You seem to have an id attribute, so let's use that.

```
index = {}
for node in result:
    index[node["id"]] = node
```

This gives us a dictionary of all of your objects, which can be accessed by their id by simply going `index[id]`. I've done this so that we don't have to waste time finding them every single time.

Now let's go find some children.

```
for node in result:
    parent_id = node["parent"]
    if parent_id in index:
        parent = index[parent_id]
        if "child" not in parent:
            parent["child"] = []
        parent["child"].append(node)
```

That should give you the result you were looking for. The solution here is quite optimizable - but I've written in this way to help you understand what is happening, so that you can adapt it to your usage.

Comment: Thanks but I need to remove the node from main tree once added to child branch